# how read only values from CSV in node.js

Tags: node.js, csv

i have the follow CSV [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z95Mo.png)

and the follow [script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmcjM.png) :

and the follow [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSI8E.png) :

... but i want only `marco;campione`

how can i do?

Comment: why do you post text in images ?? post the text directly please

Comment: You can use an array and push all the values into it on the `data` event and call it on `end` with the `login:password` `shifted` from it.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you the expected result. Please modify as per your requirement

```
    var secondRow=[];

    fs.createReadStream('Book1.csv').pipe(csv()).on('data',function(data){
        secondRow.push(data);
    }).on('end',function(data){

        console.log("Read fininshed");
        secondRow.shift();
        console.log(secondRow[0]);
    });
```